# Trying to animate a show/hide definition list with hidden attribute (hidden attribute causes animation to not work)

Tags: css, css-transitions, accessibility, css-animations, hidden

I'm building an accessible accordion using a definition list.  I have this working well, where the `<dt>` contains a `<button>` which when clicked toggles an `aria-expanded` from true/false and toggles a `hidden` attribute on the corresponding `<dd>`. There's other things going on for accessibility but that's the basics for the list and the show/hide.

The show/hide display of the `dd` is then controlled via a hidden attribute selector (in this case, this is coming from the bootstrap stylesheet):

```
[hidden] {
  display: none!important;
}
```

The show/hide functionality right now is a hard show/hide and I'm trying to add a nice animation via css transitions (this needs to work in IE11 where transitions are supported.)

I built a simple POC for the animation at http://jsfiddle.net/jokvqy6u/ which just toggles a `show` and `hide` class. This was just something I could quickly throw together and send out to our marketing team to illustrate the animation to get feedback on.

I thought I'd be able to just easily add `hidden` and `:not(hidden)` selectors to the POC and it would work just fine, then I could retrofit into the real accordion, but the animation doesn't seem to work with `hidden` attributes on the html.  You can see a demo of that at http://jsfiddle.net/6zmdhqrn/2/ where the 2nd item animates because it **does not** have a `hidden` attribute. Items 1 and 3 have `hidden` attributes and do not even open up.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get my transitions working with `hidden` attributes?

**EDIT** I have it sort of half working at http://jsfiddle.net/6zmdhqrn/3/ by overriding the `[hidden]` selector coming from bootstrap with some important statements.  I still get a hard show, but the hide slides up.  I suspect it has to do with the element being `display:none` where the animations have no dimensions/info to start animating from? Still looking for info/tips on how to get the opening animation.

Answer (score 2):

You guessed right, the problem here is `display` isn’t an [animatable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) CSS property.

You need to base your animation on an animatable property, such as `opacity` for example.

Here’s a quick demo:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (el.classList.contains('visible'))
    el.classList.remove('visible');
  else
    el.classList.add('visible');
})
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="visible">some content!</div>
<button>toggle visibility</button>
```

As you may have noticed, setting the opacity to 0 doesn’t hide the element completely (i.e. it still takes up space). In case this is something undesirable, you may consider animating a different property, such as width or height.